# Moved ajax code doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm bad with titles, sorry.

I had a working ajax code, that I moved into a separate function ('sendForm') - after this it stopped working, redirects to the actual PHP and gives undefined index warnings.

I think the code will be the best explanation:

```
function sendForm(_type, _func) {
  $.ajax( {
    url:      "/lib/auth.php",
    type:     "POST",
    data:     { type: _type,
                js: true,
                form: $('#auth_form').serialize()
              },
    success:  _func(_result) /* This should maybe be just '_func'? Either way, same behavior */
  } );
}

function loginEvent() {
  /* This works if not commented

    $.ajax( {
    url:      "/lib/auth.php",
    type:     "POST",
    data:     { type: 'login',
                js: true,
                form: $('#auth_form').serialize()
              },
    success:  function(_result) {
      if (_result == "true")
        window.location = '/index.html';
      else {
        $('h4.header').removeClass('hide');
        $('input[name=password]').val('');
      }
    }
  } );*/

  /* Trying to call the function, with an inline function as argument*/
  sendForm('login', function(_result) {
      if (_result == "true")
        window.location = '/index.html';
      else {
        $('h4.header').removeClass('hide');
        $('input[name=password]').val('');
      }
    }
  );

  return false;
}
```

And of course the warnings, from /lib/auth.php which shouldn't even open as a page:

```
Notice: Undefined index: form ...
Notice: Undefined index: type ...
Notice: Undefined index: js ...
```

I'm probably overlooking something, so thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the console logging?  Are you sure that "$" is available inside your sendForm() function?

Comment: How is this function being triggered? By clicking a button? If it's a button, is it of type `submit`? If so, are you correctly preventing the default submit behavior? Also, your `success` callback is definitely incorrect. You're invoking the function immediately. Just use `success: _func`.

Comment: @Kevin_Kinsey No console output, why wouldn't it be - to be clear, the code is posted as is, in the same file.

Comment: @B.Fleming Yeah, that's probably it, I forgot the 'event.preventDefault()'.

Comment: @B.Fleming Just tested, that was the problem. I'm just surprised it even worked before, if it didn't I'd probably catch it right away.

Comment: @areuz I'm glad to hear you got it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of documenting the solution outside of the comments, it was determined that there was a missing `event.preventDefault()` call during form submission.